# проверка объекта класса на истинность

Tags: c++, классы

Имеется класс S и объект этого класса v.

Что нужно прописать в классе, чтобы if в функции вида

```
void f (S v) {
    if (v) {
        std::cout << "HI" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

работал корректно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перегрузить оператор приведения к `bool` (и оператор логического отрицания заодно) :

```
explicit operator bool(void) const { return m_good; }

bool operator not(void) const { return not m_good; }
```

Comment: Проверил, отрицание можно не перегружать. Оно работает и с `operator bool`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Можно и не перегружать, однако обычно их имеет смысл перегружать вместе. Это примерно как операторы == и !=.

Comment: Не, я про то, что `!foo` работает даже если перегружен только `operator bool`, без `operator!`.